# Returning a promise from isolate scope directive with `&` binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Oc2OjgMAaXTrmpqdeZzp?p=preview) I have an array of directives that return a promise mapped to a function in the controller, but `$scope.run.then` is `undefined`. What's wrong with this code?

HTML

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div dir1 x="item.x" on-complete="item.onComplete()"></div>
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module("app", [])

.controller('ctl', function($scope) {

  $scope.run.then(function(response){
      alert(response);
  });

  $scope.items = [{x: 1, onComplete: $scope.run},
                 {x: 2, onComplete: $scope.run},
                 {x: 3, onComplete: $scope.run}];

})

.directive('dir1', function ($timeout,$http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',          
        scope: {
            x: '=',
            onComplete: '&'         
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
            scope.onComplete = $http.get('page.html');
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: Have you changed the requirement of needing to know when all the requests have finished in all directives?

Comment: yes, if I receive a notification from each directive is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.directive('dir1', function ($timeout,$http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',          
        scope: {
            x: '<',
            onComplete: '&'         
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("x", function(newValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    var url = "page"+newValue+".html"; 
                    var httpPromise =  $http.get(url);
                    scope.onComplete({$promise: httpPromise});
                };
            });
        }       
    };
})
```

When using expression `&` binding, the parsed expression evaluation function accepts a local variables context object.

When the directive invokes the `scope.onComplete(locals)` function, the Angular Expression defined by the `on-complete` attribute is evaluated using the parent scope. Any variables defined in the local context object will override parent scope variables.

The promise created by the directive is exposed as `$promise`.

**RECOMMENDED:** Prefix local variables with dollar signs `$` to distinguish them from parent scope variables.

For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).

### Usage

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div dir1 x="item.x" on-complete="item.onComplete($promise)"></div>
  </div>
```

```
.controller('ctl', function($scope) {
    
      $scope.items = [
                 {x: 1, onComplete: run},
                 {x: 2, onComplete: run},
                 {x: 3, onComplete: run}
      ];

      function run(promise) {
          promise.then(function(response){
              console.log("OK", response.status);
              console.log("URL", response.config.url); 
          }).catch(functon(response) {
              console.log("ERROR",response.status);
              console.log("URL", response.config.url);
          });
      };
})
```